# I am getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" in my program yet cant find the source to fix it

Tags: python

I have got a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` but I can't find the problem.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
new[x] = new(x)+x
x = x+1
```

Comment: `new` is a list. You probably meant to use `[]`, not `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use parenthesis () for list. It is mainly used in calling a function.

Correct syntax would be

```
new[x] = new[x]+1
x= x+1
```

Always use the square bracket [], with its correct index value for accessing an element from the list.

Please do see the below attachment:
[image]

Comment: I guess you might be using inside loop. So, use it like
for x in range(length(new)):
   new[x] = new[x] + x
   x = x + 1